# Finite cyclic group action on Kähler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, group-actions

Let us have a Kähler manifold $M,$ and a smooth action $\phi$ of $\mathbb{Z}/k$ on it, preserving the Kähler structure of it. Then the fixed set of this action $$\text{Fix}(\phi)=\sqcup_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$$ is a disjoint union of Kähler submanifolds $F_{\alpha}$, by the general theory.
 Now, having a fixed point $p\in F_{\alpha}$ **is it true (and why)** that the 1-eigenspace of the map induced by the action of generator of $\mathbb{Z}/k$ 
$$\phi_*:T_p M\rightarrow T_p M$$ is exactly $T_p F_{\alpha}?$

Comment: Yes, but this has not much to do with the Kähler hypothesis. The point is that the action around $p$ is linearizable, i.e. in appropriate coordinates it is of the form $(z_1,\ldots ,z_n)\mapsto (\lambda _1z_1,\ldots ,\lambda _nz_n)$. Then your assertion follows easily.

Comment: I know that this works if there was an action of a continuous group, say $S^1,$ but not sure when it is of discrete subgroup only?

Comment: In nearly complete generality, if $G$ is a compact Lie group acting smoothly on a smooth manifold $M$, and $S \subset M$ is a $G$-invariant submanifold, then the normal bundle $NS$ is a $G$-vector bundle and there is an equivariant diffeomorphism from $NS$ to a neighorhood of $S$ inside $G$.